# Split Select-String

Tags: powershell, split

Given this variable

```sh
$foo = help | Select-String powershell
```

Trying a split will fail

```
PS > $foo.split()
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]
does not contain a method named 'split'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $foo.split()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

How can I split this variable?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The string value of the matched line is in the Line property of the MatchInfo object.

```
$foo.Line.split()
```

Answer (score 1):

Split is a String method, so it must be called on a string.

```sh
[string] $foo = help | Select-String powershell
```

Or

```sh
$foo = help | Select-String powershell | Out-String
```

Comment: While this works, it is not exactly embracing the nature of PowerShell i.e. it outputs objects not merely text. :-)