# What constitutes a "line" for Select-String method in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, split, select-string

I would expect that `Select-String` consider `\r\n` (carriage-return + newline) the end of a line in Powershell.

However, as can be seen below, `abc` matches the whole the whole input:

```
PS C:\Tools\hashcat> "abc`r`ndef" | Select-String -Pattern "abc"

abc
def
```

If I break the string up into two parts, then `Select-String` behaves as I would expect:

```
PS C:\Tools\hashcat> "abc", "def" | Select-String -Pattern "abc"

abc
```

How can I give `Select-String` a string whose lines are terminated by `\r\n`, and then make this cmdlet only returns those strings that contain a match?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846685/split-select-string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) operates on each (stringified on demand<sup>[1]</sup>) *input object*.
- A *multi-line* string such as `` "abc`r`ndef" `` is a *single* input object.

  - By contrast, `"abc", "def"` is a string *array* with two elements, passed as *two* input objects.
- To ensure that the *lines* of a multi-line string are passed *individually*, split the string into an *array of lines* using PowerShell's `-split` operator: `` "abc`r`ndef" -split "`r?`n" ``

  - (The `?` makes the `` `r `` optional so as to also correctly deal with `` `n ``-only (LF-only, Unix-style) line endings.)

In short:

```
"abc`r`ndef" -split "`r?`n" | Select-String -Pattern "abc"
```

The equivalent, using a PowerShell string literal with regular-expression (regex) escape sequences (the RHS of `-split` is a regex):

```
"abc`r`ndef" -split '\r?\n' | Select-String -Pattern "abc"
```

---

It is somewhat unfortunate that the `Select-String` documentation talks about operating on *lines* of text, given that the real units of operations are input *objects* - which may themselves comprise multiple lines, as we've seen.
Presumably, this comes from the *typical* use case of providing input objects via the `Get-Content` cmdlet, which outputs a text file's lines *one by one*.

Note that `Select-String` doesn't return the matching strings *directly*, but wraps them in [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) objects containing helpful metadata about the match. 
Even there the line metaphor is present, however, as it is the `.Line` property that contains the matching *string*.

---

#### [1] Optional reading: How `Select-String` stringifies input objects

If an input object isn't a string already, it is converted to one, though possibly not in the way you might expect:

**Loosely speaking, the `.ToString()` method is called on each non-string input object**<sup>[2]</sup>
, which for non-strings is ***not* the same as the representation you get with PowerShell's *default output formatting*** (the latter is what you see when you print an object to the *console* or use `Out-File`, for instance); by contrast, it *is* the same representation you get with *string interpolation* in a double-quoted string (when you embed a variable reference or command in `"..."`, e.g., `"$HOME"` or `"$(Get-Date)"`).

Often, `.ToString()` just yields the name of the object's *type*, without containing any instance-specific information; e.g., `$PSVersionTable` stringifies to `System.Management.Automation.PSVersionHashTable`.

```
# Matches NOTHING, because Select-String sees
# 'System.Management.Automation.PSVersionHashTable' as its input.
$PSVersionTable | Select-String PSVersion
```

**In case you *do* want to search the default output format line by line**, use the following idiom:

```
... | Out-String -Stream | Select-String ...
```

However, note that **for non-string input it is more robust and preferable for subsequent processing to filter the input by *querying properties* with a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) condition.**

That said, **there is a strong case to be made for `Select-String` needing to *implicitly* apply `Out-String -Stream` stringification, as discussed in [this GitHub feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726)**.

---

<sup>[2] More accurately, `.psobject.ToString()` is called, either as-is, or - if the object's `ToString` method supports an `IFormatProvider`-typed argument - as `.psobject.ToString([cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)` so as to obtain a *culture-invariant* representation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for more information.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
"abc`r`ndef"
```

is one string which if you echo (`Write-Output`) out in console would result in:

```
PS C:\Users\gpunktschmitz> echo "abc`r`ndef"
abc
def
```

The `Select-String` will echo out every string where "abc" is part of it. As "abc" is part the string this very string will be selected.

```
"abc", "def"
```

is a list of two strings. Using the `Select-String` here will first test "abc" and then "def" if the pattern matches "abc". As only the first one matches only it will be selected.

Use the following to split the string into a list and select only the elements containing "abc"

```
"abc`r`ndef".Split("`r`n") | Select-String -Pattern "abc"
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically Mr. Guenther Schmitz explained the correct usage of `Select-String`, but I want to just add some points to support his answer.

1. I did some reverse engineering work against this `Select-String` cmdlet. It's in the Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.dll. Some relevant code snippets are as follows, notice these are codes from reverse engineering for reference, not the actual source code.

   ```
   string text = inputObject.BaseObject as string;
   ...
   matchInfo = (inputObject.BaseObject as MatchInfo);
   object operand = ((object)matchInfo) ?? ((object)inputObject);
   flag2 = doMatch(operand, out matchInfo2, out text);
   ```

   We can find out that it just treat the inputObject as a whole string, it doesn't do any split.
2. I don't find the actual source code of this cmdlet on github, probably this utility part is not open source yet. But I find the [unit test](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/cc3ffd8349547e968c00e0b175a6abe348087b41/test/powershell/Modules/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String.Tests.ps1) of this `Select-String`.

   ```
   $testinputone = "hello","Hello","goodbye"
   $testinputtwo = "hello","Hello"
   ```

   The test strings they are using for unit test are actually lists of strings. It means that they were not even thinking about your use case and very possibly it's just designed to accept input of string collection.
3. However if we look at the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) of Microsoft regarding `Select-String` we do see it talks about **line** a lot while it can't recognize a **line** in a string. My personal guess is the concept of **line** is only meaningful while the cmdlet accept a file as an input, in the case the file is like a list of string, each item in the list represents a single line.

Hope it can make things more clear.